# adding a date and time fields in a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm trying to create an event, the event has a date and a time field. When creating the table for `protest` I didn't add a time field, so I had to run a migration to add a time field. But I am now having issues when creating the form. What is the elegant solution to create a time and date field?

```
class CreateProtests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :protests do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :location
      t.datetime :starts_at
      t.references :creator, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
    end
  end
end
```

I then added a field for the time of day:

```
class AddStartsAtTimeOfDayToProtests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :protests, :starts_at_time_of_day, :datetime
  end
end
```

protests/new.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><h2>Create A Protest</h2></div>
    <div class="card-block">

    <%= form_for(@protest, url: protests_path, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :location %>
        <%= f.text_field :location, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label "Date:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :starts_at, value: "02/16/13", id: "dp2"%>
      </div>



     <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label "Time:" %>
       <%= f.time_select :starts_at, ignore_date: true, class: "form-control"%>
     </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :image %>
        <%= f.file_field :image, as: :file, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: ```{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2vfBeil4CYxGovHenhuJ7nEP1NKAeOLElvGRH0fmGIbDhWvhVPhd8Xh2dMRqYBOwPTjXK83CPmDgZ7so+D528w==",
 "protest"=>{"name"=>"cookie", "description"=>"jimmu", "location"=>"New York NY", "starts_at"=>"02/16/13", "starts_at(4i)"=>"03", "starts_at(5i)"=>"43"},
 "commit"=>"Create"}```

Comment: @Subash I get an error ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors in ProtestsController#create because in the params the time is not being stored in the field  `:starts_at_time_of_day` and it saves hour and minutes separate

Comment: Why did you add starts_at_time_of_day?. starts_at is a datetime so it includes the date and the time. You don't need two columns in the database.

Comment: You need to use the date and time value from the form in controller and create a `datetime` object to save in `starts_at_time_of_day` field or remove `starts_at_time_of_day` from your model and use 2 different fields

Comment: How do I grab the time in the form using just the `:starts_at` column?

Comment: Have you think about insert time only string data like `"09:30 pm"` to the table string column `"starts_at"`

Answer (score 0):

The Date and Time are both captured in the single column `:starts_at` so you don't need another column for the time of day.

Your form should just have:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label "Starts At:" %>
   <%= f.datetime_select :starts_at, class: "form-control"%>
 </div>
```

Here is a link to the docs:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/datetime_select

Comment: This would give me year month and date in the form, I just want hour and minute.

Answer (score 0):

add `date_field` for Date and `time_field` for the time to have the two fields as follows.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Date:" %>
    <%= f.date_field :starts_at, class: "form-control"%>
  </div>



 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label "Time:" %>
   <%= f.time_field :starts_at, class: "form-control"%>
 </div>
```